# Identifying security vulnerabilities in answers

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I read this [blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/26/copying-code-from-stack-overflow-you-might-be-spreading-security-vulnerabilities/?cb=1) and have the following questions and feature request. Please help.

Most of the times, the answers are approved by users who might just want "a" solution to the problem. They might not be knowledgeable enough to know the performance/security threats in those answers.

1. Is commenting on such answers the best way to notify the future readers? *If there are many comments, it might just get drowned in it*
2. Or is downvoting a better option? *I don't think it is*
3. Would SO consider adding a tags section into the answer? *This is probably a feature request, but I don't know whether there is something in the works already.*

Comment: @WeareMonica. I guess Code Review and Software Engineering could also be examples of sites that could potentially have this issue

Comment: @JustinKrejcha Also, there's StackOverflow in languages other than English, e.g., [Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: What's a "tag section"? And how is that supposed to help here?

Comment: Hopefully developers working on production applications aren't copying code found online without understanding it.

Comment: Here's an earlier question  about that study: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/334811/334566

Comment: @dustytrash Some do, some don't. That study certainly found plenty of evidence of carelessness. Here's one example involving Samsung, https://stackoverflow.com/q/48610180/4014959 which got reported [here](https://www.xda-developers.com/samsung-bixby-baseball-card-tracking-app-galaxy-s8/).

Answer (score 5):

It seems like the accepted convention is to *comment and/or edit* the post so that any vulnerabilities are identified, as long as the criteria for editing (it should not significantly change the answer) is met.

Something like...

> One should take care to appropriately mitigate [...]

...should be sufficient. An alternative could be to add your own answer that has the vulnerability identified and fixed.

It's hard to find data for this, but I've seen this on some answers across SO.